# MassTransit 3 w/ Azure - Consumer not receiving message > 8k

Tags: .net, azure, servicebus, masstransit

I have set up a C# solution using Masstransit 3.1.2 along with Azure Service Bus and everything seems to be working until I recently noticed that messages > 8k were not being received by my subscribers.  I don't really see any errors.  If the same message type was under 8k my message is received without any issues.

After much research, I'm fairly confident that this is a constraint with MassTransit and not Azure Service Bus since I can consume my message directly using the Azure SDK.

Is there a configuration setting that I'm missing?  I'd hate to go the route of setting up an external message data like Mongo to receive these messages.  My messages won't be more than 64k (which is Azure's standard limit, I believe).

Comment: I verified that messages up to 256K work fine using this benchmark and specifying a ```--payload=250000``` to the message body. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Benchmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the host configurator, you can try changing the `TransportType` to NetTcp (instead of the default AMQP) - there might be a limitation in the message size when using AMQP I'm not aware of - but honestly I've never seen the too big message issue and I know I've had messages larger than 8KB.

```
host.TransportType = TransportType.NetMessaging;
```

Comment: Changing the TranportType solved my issue locally.  However, after publishing my WebJob out to Azure, I'm encountering the same issues.  I've also tried updating the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to 3.1.4 to no avail.

Comment: Using MassTransit 3.2 with TransportType NetMessaging and WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 3.1.4 throws the following error:

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: 
Exception while executing function: Program.Start ---> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: An exception occurred during bus creation ---> `  

I had to use MassTransit 3.1.2 to make NetMessaging work

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus has a per-message size limit of 256 kBytes across all transports (HTTPS, AMQP, NetMessaging)

Comment: Thanks Clemens, and yes, I just verified (using MassTransit-Benchmark) that I can send up to 256K via MassTransit using Azure Service Bus. So there is something else at play with this question.